# Linux command to delete all files except .git folder?

Tags: linux, git

I want to **delete all of the current directory's content *except* for the `.git/` folder** before I copy the new files into the branch.

What's the linux command for that?

Comment: In most cases I'd just `rm -rf *` which would skip *all* dot-files, then manually rm any leftovers as needed.  To be particularly fancy you can use `find` but it's also possible to just `ls -A > /tmp/doit` then edit `/tmp/doit` to rm or rm-r everything except `.git`, and that's often easier.

Comment: or just move `.git` to a diff folder temporary then remove all and then move it back

Comment: If you need this operation right after cloning, then you can simply clone with the `-n` (`--no-checkout`) option: `git clone -n -b <branch> <repository> <directory>`.

Comment: Almost duplicate question, but for any file/directory: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/remove-all-files-directories-except-for-one-file

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Resetting the index is cheap, so

```
git rm -rf .
git clean -fxd
```

Then you can reset the index (with `git reset`) or go straight on to checking out a new branch.

Comment: Nice! This is a good git-specific solution I wasn't aware of, which may well be a better one in this case.

Comment: To reset the index, neither `git reset` nor `git checkout` worked for me. I have to use `git reset --hard`.

Comment: Neat use of the `-x` option to bypass the gitignore

Comment: Would adding `git reset --hard` as first command here have any benefit?

Comment: if we need to remove tracker files:  `git update-ref -d refs/heads/`

Answer (score 19):

With find and prune option.

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

---

**Edit:** For two directories `.git` and `dist`

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o \( \! -path ./dist \) -exec rm -rf {} \; 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: doesn't remove any folders

Comment: now it works, but it gives me errors saying `find: './scss': no such file or directory` but still deletes everything. weird

Comment: PxL, If you can suppress errors that I'm getting about `no such file or directory` This is my answer of choice.

Comment: @EricSteinborn: added stderr redirection to a null file

Comment: I know its a different question than the initial question, but how would you add another ignored folder? Say "dist/" and ".git"?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think redirecting all possible errors to null is a good idea in general.
Why not using the `find` option `-delete` instead of executing `rm`?

Comment: @Antonio: I agree with you regarding redirecting errors. From the docs for `-delete` option: `Because -delete implies -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.`

Comment: Detailing the difference between this answer and mine: `-prune` effectively limits `find` to the current directory level, so instead of going through the tree and deleting each file, it uses `rm -r` to delete each file or folder in the root directory.  And as @P̲̳x͓L̳ noted, `-prune` precludes `-delete`, since `-delete` isn't recursive.

Comment: This is just so convinient!

Comment: Adding `-d` to the command will depth sort so dirs are deleted last, then you no longer need the redirect.

Answer (score 14):

As Crayon mentioned in the comments, the easy solution would be to just move .git out of the directory, delete everything, and then move it back in.  But if you want to do it the fancy way, `find` has got your back:

```
find -not -path "./.git/*" -not -name ".git" | grep git
find -not -path "./.git/*" -not -name ".git" -delete
```

The first line I put in there because with `find`, I always want to double-check to make sure it's finding what I think it is, before running the `-delete`.

Edit: Added `-not -name ".git"`, which keeps it from trying to delete the `.git` directory, and suppresses the errors.  Depending on the order `find` tries to delete things, it may fail on non-empty directories.

Comment: Does this require the first line to run?

Comment: Answered my own question, no.

Comment: So this works just fine, I feel that the non quoted version was more widely accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: The major difference between this and the accepted answer is not the quotes (I have those to protect from shells trying to prematurely expand the glob), but the `-prune`.  It's a different way of accomplishing the same task.  And as for the first line: any time you are running a `find -delete`, you should run it without the `-delete` first, to make sure you're not doing something unintended.

Comment: Good answer. When replacing `-path "./.git/*"` with `-path "*/.git/*"` then it works for excluding multiple git repositories which are under one common directory. Like `projects/project1/.git` and `projects/project2/.git` then this can be run directly inside the `projects/` directory.

Answer (score 11):

One way is to use `rm -rf *`, which will delete all files from the folder except the dotfiles and dotfolders like `.git`. You can then delete the dotfiles and dotfolders one by one, so that you don't miss out on important dotfiles like `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` later.

Another approach would be to move your `.git` folder out of the directory and then going back and deleting all the contents of the folder and moving the `.git` folder back.

```
mv .git/ ../
cd ..
rm -rf folder/*
mv .git/ folder/
cd folder
```

Comment: I do think `rm -r *` is the best solution. Keeping .gitignore and other files like that can be important.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `ls | grep -v ".git"` ; do rm -rf $i; done; rm .gitignore;
```

the additional `rm` at the end will remove the special `.gitignore`. Take that off if you do need the file.

Comment: -1 The user wants to delete all files except the `.git` files, while those are the same ones  you seem to be deleting.

Comment: @mu無 They used grep -v, which inverts the match.  But it's still a very awkward solution, when there are much better options.

Comment: @cincodenada The other problem was that this doesn't delete remaining dotfiles within the folder. Also, initially there was some error with the code which has been corrected now which was giving me `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'`

Comment: @TimWolla You're right, but life would be better if those special characters could not/were not used in file names

Answer (score 1):

as [CB Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22347541/12387614) mention:
I want to remove the history of `tracker files` too.

```bash
git rm -rf .
git clean -fxd
git update-ref -d refs/heads/master #or main or ...
```

Answer (score -5):

## should find all the files and directories that with the name .git

```
find .  -name .git
```

## should find all the file and directories not named .git

```
find . -not -name .git
```

## delete all the files that you find

```
find . -not -name .git -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

be sure that the find is doing what you want

if you want to delete directories change the rm command to `rm -rvf`
I include the `v` option to see the files that are deleted.

if you want to make sure about the files before you delete them
pipe the find command to a file and review the results

Comment: Try running `find . -not -name .git | grep git` - you'll see that you're trying to delete all the files in the `.git` directory, becuase they don't have ".git" in their filenames.  You're looking for -path and some wildcards.

Comment: that is why the command i gave to delete the files has the '-not' in front of it.  i'll review my answer.

Comment: My original comment had a typo where I omitted the -not, which I've corrected.  See my corrected comment as to why you need to learn more about how the `find` command works.

Comment: yeah, luckily It's a git repo and I could reclone after testing this out.